# How can I get Date from couchdb?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, couchrest

I need to take a date from server but not from client in couchdb, is there any way how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

@JasonSmith described a way of achieving this using a show function

[CouchDB: Get server-time with an http request in CouchApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136028/couchdb-get-server-time-with-an-http-request-in-couchapp)